# how to return mac address using ioctl only 4 hex instead 6 hex

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

I have the following code:(compiled as shared library)

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int (*ioctl_t)(int, unsigned long int, char *);

int ioctl(int d, unsigned long int request, char *argp) 
   { 
   int out; 
   ioctl_t realioctl;

   void *libhandle; /* mac address here */ 
   char data[14] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
   struct ifreq *temp; 

   temp = (struct ifreq *)argp;
   if (request == 35111) 
      { 
      memcpy(temp->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, data, 14);
      out = 0; 
      } 
   else 
      {
      libhandle = dlopen("/lib/libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY); 
      realioctl = dlsym(libhandle, "ioctl");
      out = realioctl(d, request, argp);
      dlclose(libhandle); 
      } 

   return out; 
   }
```

This code returns mac address "000000000000" because the var "data[14]" is hard coded.

OK, so far so good.. But that is not what I want.. What I realy want is to return just a portion of that..

Instead return a full mac-address of 12 chars(6hex), but I want to show only the first 8(4hex) like: "00000000".

If I change the char data length to 10, 8, 4 and add a random number like {0xcf,0x7f,0xg6,0xd1} .. it will be "cf7fg6d10000" (the code add/complete with zeros in the end) which I don't want.

I just want to have returned "cf7fg6d1".

Could anyone help me?
------>

Changed the code line from:

> memcpy(temp->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, data, 14);

to:

> temp->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1]=0xc9;
>     temp->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2]=0x4c;
>     temp->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3]=0xcf;
>     temp->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4]=0xf0;

Note position 0 is not declared, as well 5. System auto fills with "00" on both positions.

So I went ahead and changed:

1) (net/if.h) ifreq structure IFHWADDRLEN value from 6 to 4 -> same results

2) (sys/socket.h) sockaddr struct var sa_data[14]; to sa_data[4]; -> same results

I am totally LOST! Any expert would give a glimpse !?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. 'This code' is an unreadable mess.  Please fix it! Indent and lay it out in an orthodox manner.  Also, why is the question tagged OSX? Your library name doesn't exist on Mac OS X.

Comment: Is your `uname` function relevant here or can that be removed from the question?

Comment: It's really not relevant. Only ioctl .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do exactly what you are asking.

The MAC address field in the structure populated by  the `ioctl` call (`ifreq.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data`) is a 6-byte array. There is no way to communicate anything other than 6 bytes back to the caller. If you try to pass back a too-small structure, the client will likely crash when it tries to read the amount of data is expecting. If you try to pass back too much data the client will not look for it (typical caller use will be something like `printf("MAC address is %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);`) and if there are any following fields they will likely be corrupted.

`ifreq.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data` is not a NUL-terminated string, so you cannot insert a NUL earlier to make it look shorter.

The only option you have is changing the data being returned to the caller. You can replace any bytes you like in the actual MAC address with zeros, other hard-coded values, random values, etc.

Comment: I thought exactly that, but I dont know how to change/or create a new structure array to send back to the caller. I dont think my caller will crash with a small structure. Do you think its possible to modify the ifreq string to return only 4-byte?

Comment: No, I do not think it's possible.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is pretty mangled. I couldn't quite figure out if you wanted to clip it to a particular size, or if the buffer would be null terminated

Use [char *strrchr(const char *s, int c)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr) to find the terminating '0' if it is null terminated or [void *memrchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memchr) if not.

If you need to clip the string on a max size as well, then use min(a, b).

Then  you can drop a actual char 0 on your string, or use a strncpy

But perhaps you'd better tidy up the code to readability?

Comment: Sorry about the mess.  The portion I really need functioning is ioctl. Uname doesn't matter. I did not followed your explanation. Would you mind to show me where you suggest the change?

Comment: So you want the hex text of out? Or the actual int value of out shifted down

Comment: This won't work. The structure in question is an array of known size where zeros are possible. It's not a C string.

Comment: The return value is 'out'. That is a int being returned from the ioctl, and since we don't know what the request was, we also don't know what the return value is. There are a lot of uses for ioctl from libc.so. He is also requesting a return value as a hex string. So the int would have to be converted first to hex and the string clipped OR the number shifted in some way.

A bit short of info.

Comment: We know that the `ioctl` being handled is `SIOCGIFHWADDR` (35111 / 0x8927). In that case the result put into `ifreq.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data` is raw data bytes, not a NUL-terminated string (it can't be, because a MAC address might legitimately contain `0x00`).

Comment: I modified <net/if.h> for the fuction ifreq where "IFHWADDRLEN=6" to "IFHWADDRLEN=4", but got same results(zeros in the end). I also printed to a file the variables and got the caller sent: d=3, request=35111, argp=xp0

Comment: Modifying `if.h` will only help if: (1) you recompile every program that uses it. It looks like you're trying to build an LD_PRELOAD hook library here, so I doubt you want to do that. (2) Callers actually check the struct size. As I mentioned, many programs are hard-coded to assume 6-byte MACs.  If you give them a smaller structure they'll still try to read 6 bytes and either crash or read garbage.

Comment: Good point, so if I have the caller source code I can change that right?

Comment: How about sa_len and sa_family? would that affect the sa_data length IF they would declared?